# python SSHClient connection problem with paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have .ppk file and I am using paramiko module to create connection but it return me error,

Here is my code

```
import paramiko

hostname = 'sftp.xyz.eu' 
myuser   = 'myusername'
mySSHK   = 'file.ppk'
password = '9SMxT2rAsybsLWt'
sshcon   = paramiko.SSHClient()  # will create the object
sshcon.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # no known_hosts error
sshcon.connect(hostname, username = myuser, password = password, key_filename = mySSHK)
print(sshcon)
```

it return me this erorr please correct me

```
sshcon.connect(hostname, username = myuser, password = password, key_filename = mySSHK)
  File "/home/test/Documents/xml_read_ftp/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/home/test/Documents/xml_read_ftp/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session
```

Now i have convert my file with public_key with puty

Now i am getting this error

```
self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
  File "/home/test/Documents/xml_read_ftp/paramiko/client.py", line 824, in missing_host_key

paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server 'sftp.xyz.xyz' not found in known_hosts
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new question, instead of changing the topic of this one. Though your new question was asked many times already. Do some research before asking.

Comment: Martin please help me

Comment: yes i did this dear

Comment: What did you do? Did you post a new question after doing an extensive research?

Comment: i am doing extensive research i want to implement this

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, you are trying to use a PuTTY/Pageant key (`file.ppk`) while you should be using an OpenSSH key: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect

Try exporting your key to an OpenSSH key and retry with the OpenSSH key.

**EDIT**

Also, you are using the `password` argument in `connect` but it would be better to use the `passphrase` argument as, I guess, this is the key password.

In case `password` is the user password, remove it: you are trying to connect with key authentication, you don't need any user password.

Comment: I have id_rsa.pub this key also

Comment: with this i am getting same error

Comment: Did you convert the key as Martin mentioned ?

Comment: Martin mentioned? I don't have an idea

Comment: Martin Prikryl gave you a link to a post showing how to export your PPK key to an OpenSSH key in a comment to your question.
Did you follow that procedure ?

Comment: yes i have seen that, and i am going to implement this. Let you know in few min..

Comment: i did this but now i got this error  Server 'sftp.xyz.xyz' not found in known_hosts

Comment: That is weird.
Could you please update your question and add the modifications you made and the new problem you are facing.

Comment: Ok i will do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208914/discussion-between-python-logix-and-stinger).